# Fixing div width for screen resolution changes

Tags: css, column-width

I have a problem with my css and html code. 
[image: Width seems not to work]

When I open the page normally it works, but when I change screen resolution, the .content-body class (the light blue with diagonal) does not fulfill the entire page width (there is that pink column). Could anyone help? Thank you.

That's the whole css code:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #ffe1d9;
  width: inherit;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.top-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100% - 25px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ffe1d9;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.presentation-header {
  //position: relative;
  ////padding-top: 0;
  //top: 150px;
  //z-index: 999;
  max-width: 1000px;
  //margin: 0 auto;
}

li.header-menu-item {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  a {
    color: #666167;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover {
      color: #111111;
      font-weight: 400;
      box-shadow: #111111;
    }
    span {
      &:hover {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #60629d;
      }
    }
  }
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #60629d;
}

.header-menu {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 70px;
  text-align: right;
}


#slogan {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#slogan-img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#button {
  background: #1d1c24;
  padding: 15.5px 51px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: SansSerif, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;

}

#button:active {
  background: #000000;
}

#sign-in-button, #submit {
  background: white;
}

#sign-in-button, #next {
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

#next {
  background: #ffe1d9;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 50%;
}

#submit {
  background-color: #ffe1d9;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

#sign-in-button:active, #submit:active {
  background: #ffe6e3;
}

select {
  padding: 15px 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 0 solid;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png) no-repeat right #e9f3f5;
  background-position: 100%-15px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 7.0rem;
  line-height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: -.5rem;
  margin: initial;
}

//.padding {
//padding-top: 30px;
//padding-bottom: 50px;
//}

/*Line bellow Features*/
.span-decoration {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #caafaf;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}

/*Draws a diagonal line in a box*/
.diagonal-line-box {

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  //background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( left top, #ffe1d9  49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9  49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #ffe1d9  49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #ffe1d9  49.75%, #989cdb 50.25%); /* Standard syntax */
}

/*Draws a diagonal line in a box*/
.second_diagonal-line-box {

  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  //top: -150px;
  background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( right top, #989cdb 49.75%, #60629d 50.25%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom left, #989cdb  49.75%, #60629d 50.25%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, #989cdb  49.75%, #60629d 50.25%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #989cdb  49.75%, #60629d 50.25%); /* Standard syntax */
}

//html, .content-body {
//  width: 100%;
//}
.content-body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #989cdb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  //left: 50px;
}

#slogan-image {

}

section {

  .cashflow {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    //margin: -60px -80px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    //margin-right: -150px;
  }

  .cashflow-text {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
  }

  .cashflow, .cashflow-text {display: inline-block;}
}

section {

  .budget {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;

    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: -100px;
    margin-top: -60px;
  }

  .budget-text {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
  }

  .budget, .budget-text {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  background: #282731;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(54, 45, 105, 0.59);
  -moz-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(54, 45, 105, 0.59);
  box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(54, 45, 105, 0.59);
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -280px;

}

.wrapper.box {
  padding: 80px;

  form {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
}

.wrapper-payment {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, #ffffff 50%, #2e2935 50%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff  50%, #2e2935 50%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff  50%, #2e2935 50%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff  50%, #2e2935 50%); /* Standard syntax */
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .wrapper.box {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #button {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}


.wrapper-image {
  background: #282731;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
  -moz-box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
  //box-shadow: 22px 17px 58px 3px rgba(89,51,51,0.59);
  //margin: auto;
}

.title{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5.0rem;
  line-height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: -.5rem;
  //margin: initial;
}

.title-body {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}

//Form styling

input, label{
  display: block;
}

label {
  color: #7f7e83;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 5px 0 15px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #83828a;
  background-color: #282731;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-family: Georgia, Serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.first-part-form {
  width: 100%;

}

.form-first-left {
  width: 46%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.form-first-right {
  width: 46%;
  float: right;
}

//End form styling

.post-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  //height: 750px;
  background-color: #60629d;
  //top: -150px;
  //z-index: -10;
}

#post-content-div {
  //height: 100px;
}

#next {
  background-color: #ffe1d9;
  color: #282731;
}

#login-or-company {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#login-url {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  //float: left;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#login-url, #login-or-company {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #60629d;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}



.halfwidth {
  display: inline-block;
  width:50%;
  position: relative;
}


.second-part-form {
  label {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  h3{
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Join Now &dash; Sweety &amp; Co. Pro</title>



        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/base.css">




        <script src="/static/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/base.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="top-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header col-md-6">

            <a href="/"><img id="header-logo" src="/static/img/logo_escuro.svg" width="314" height="81"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" id="div-header-menu">
            <ul class="header-menu list-inline " id="nav">
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a class="" href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#" class=""><span>Features</span></a> </li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#" class=""><span>Pricing</span></a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#" class=""><span>Help</span></a> </li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#" type="button" role="button"
                                                id="button" class="button">JOIN NOW</a> </li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="/auth/login" class=""><span>Sign in</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container ">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row presentation-header">

                <div id="slogan" class="">


    <h2>Because</h2>
    <h2>you can't</h2>
    <h2>create</h2>
    <h2>money</h2>


    <div style="margin: 50px"></div>

    <div class="">
        <a id="sign-in-button" href="/auth/login" role="button" type="button">Sign in &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both"></div>

                </div>


                <div id="slogan-img" class="">

    <img id="slogan-image" src="/static/img/mac2.png">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 50px"></p>


                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container diagonal-line-box">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">



            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<div class="content-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section class="">

    <div class="container">
        <section class="row ">
            <h3 class="col-md-5">Features<p class="span-decoration"></p></h3>
        </section>

        <h4>Get to know SweetyPro & Co. Features</h4>

        <section>
            <img class="cashflow" src="/static/img/cashflow_144.png">

            <div class="cashflow-text">
                <h1 class="title ">Cashflow</h1>
                <p class="title-body">Organize your expenses and incomes in a platform easy to use.</p>
                <p class="title-body">Enough of losing control of the situation, your payments and outputs are always on time.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

        <section>
            <div class="budget-text">
                <h1 class="title " style="text-align: right">Budgets</h1>
                <p class="title-body" style="text-align: right">
                    Can you imagine creating budgets with just a few steps? Yes! It's possible.
                </p>
                <p class="title-body" style="text-align: right">
                    Sweety & Co. Pro helps you figure out how much to charge and making budgets turned into novice task.
                </p>
            </div>
            <img class="budget" src="/static/img/budget_144.png">
        </section>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>

        <section class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="title">Timeline</h1>
                <p class="title-body">Time is money. Thus organize yourself and your time and don't stop until you earn money.</p>
            </div>
            <img class="col-md-12" src="/static/img/timeline_144.png">
        </section>

        <section class="row padding">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="title" style="text-align: center">Fastcreate</h1>
                <p class="title-body" style="text-align: center">Running out of time? With a simple mouse click, you get access to foremost features of
                    Sweety & Co. Pro. in any gadget at any time.</p>
            </div>
            <img class="col-md-12" src="/static/img/fastcreate_144.png">
        </section>

        <section class="row">
            <h3 class="col-md-5">Join now<p class="span-decoration"></p></h3>
        </section>
        <h4>The Status of Liberty Enlightening the World was a gift of the people of France...</h4>

    </div>


            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container second_diagonal-line-box">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col-md-12">



                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container post-content">
    <div class="container">
        <section class="col-md-offset-1">

    <div id="post-content-div" class="container">
        <div id="wrapper" class=" wrapper box ">
            <div class="first-part-form">
                <h1 class="form-first-left" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Get your time and money on track</h1>
                <img class="" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 25px" src="/static/img/price.png">
            </div>
            <div style="clear: left"></div>
            <div class="second-part col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <h3>Payment method</h3>
                <p class="span-decoration"></p>
                <p class="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>

                <select >
                    <option>Credit Card</option>
                    <option>Paypal</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <form method="post" role="form">
                <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1471534484##5376f5b3fac93b1e7f29c731c668293a456aca13"></div>
                <div class="first-part-form">

                    <div class="form-first-left">
                        <label for="name">First Name</label>
                        <input id="name" name="first_name" placeholder="John" required type="text" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-first-right">
                        <label for="surname">Last Name</label>
                        <input id="surname" name="last_name" placeholder="Smith" required type="text" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <div class="form-first-left">

                        <label for="login-or-company" id="login-or-company-label">Login (company's name or yours)</label>
                        <input class="col-md-6" id="login-or-company" name="username" required type="text" value="">
                        <p id="login-url" class="col-md-2">.sweetyand.co</p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-first-right">
                        <label for="password">Password (min. 6 characters)</label>
                        <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="******" required type="password" value="">

                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                    <div class="form-first-left">

                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com" required type="email" value="">

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-first-right">
                        <label for="reemail">Re-email</label>
                        <input id="reemail" name="re_email" placeholder="john@example.com" required type="email" value="">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="second-part-form row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-md-offset-1" style="margin-top: -30px">You chose</label>
                            <h3 class="col-md-offset-1" id="dropdown-option">Credit Card</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">


                            <label class="col-md-offset-1" for="credit-card-name">Name as in credit card</label>
                            <input class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-1" id="credit-card-name" name="credit_card_name" required type="text" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">


                            <label class="col-md-offset-1" for="credit-card-number">Credit card number</label>
                            <input class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1" id="credit-card-number" name="credit_card_number" required type="text" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="row">


                                <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" for="validate">Validate</label>
                                <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3" for="cvc">CVC/CW</label>
                            </div>


                            <input class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" id="validate" name="month_card" placeholder="MM" required type="text" value="">

                            <input class="col-md-3" id="year" name="year_card" placeholder="YYYY" required type="text" value="">


                            <input class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" id="cvc" name="cvc" required type="text" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="col-md-1"></p>

                            <input class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2" id="accept_terms" name="accept_terms" required type="checkbox" value="y">
                            <p style="margin-left: 10px; color: white">I accept the terms of SweetyPro.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">

                            <input class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next                     &gt;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
            <div class="form-first-left">
                <img id="logo-form" src="/static/img/logo.svg" class="" width="200" height="71">
            </div>

            <div class="form-first-right">
                <input id="next" class="" type="button"  value="Next&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &#62;">
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="flash">
                <div class="col-md-offset-6">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>

        </div>
    </div>


        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer container">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="foot-logo" class="col-md-12" src="/static/img/sco.svg" width="129" height="79">
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post some code, or a link?

Comment: background-size: 100%;

Comment: Please provide some code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: *I have a problem with my css and html code.* how do you expect us to fix said css and html if you do not provide it?

Comment: Code provided, sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple topic:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
}
```